# personal nest api access

Tags: api, nest

I've had a Nest thermostat for a little over a year and it works well.  I also have many other Home Automation devices.  I'm a Software Engineer and I enjoy making my life easier by programming my own, personalized, solutions to Home Automation issues.  For example, I have my own weather station which reports information to Weather Underground using my own custom software.  I also have my own, home grown, web interface which integrates both the X10 devices in my house and also the Wink devices, on one page.

I would like to gather temperature readings from my Nest thermostat and integrate that information into my home temperature information, in order to get a better idea of what is happening in my house.  I signed up to be a Nest Developer and jumped through all of the hoops to get an access token in order to use the REST API.  They turned me down!

So, it sounds as if Nest is not allowing their customers to access the information from your own thermostat in your own house!  I find this closed system unacceptable!  If Nest will not allow me access, then I guess my only alternative is to replace my thermostat with some other model which is more open and accessible?

Have others run into this closed system?  Is there a way to deal with it, or is Nest simply saying, "we want your personal temperature information history, but we're not allowing you to have it, yourself."

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you don't need to get approval.  Just proceed with describing the program, etc., and get the pincode.  It works fine for a small number of users (50, I think) without approvals.